# How to use the vue-simple-spinner?

Tags: vue.js

I use the [vue-simple-spinner](https://github.com/dzwillia/vue-simple-spinner/):

in my main.js:

```
import Spinner from 'vue-simple-spinner'
....
Vue.component('vue-simple-spinner', Spinner)
```

but when I use it in the `app.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-simple-spinner></vue-simple-spinner>
  ...
```

I will get the `Unknown custom element` error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but it works well for me, did `app.vue` import as well in `main.js` or in some another file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that you're just missing including it as components in the script section.

You need to make sure that it is both registered & imported in the script section of your component.

```
<script>
import Spinner from 'vue-simple-spinner'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Spinner
  }
}
</script>
```